# Ice cube in a pool

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, ice

Imagine this situation: Large ice cube placed at the bottom of an empty pool starts to dissolve. I was wondering if it is possible for cube to start float in the water? If yes, what  fraction of the cube needs to dissolve?

Comment: Ice doesn't "dissolve" when it turns to liquid, it "melts".

Comment: Consider whether asking for help in a running competition (http://fykos.org/problems) is fair or not to others. You'll learn nothing about solving physics problems, since you don't seem to be motivated to solve them. If you cannot solve them, read the solutions which will be publicly available after deadline.

Comment: Related Meta question: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4940/2451